# So I have this idea for a videogame. How do I make sure it gets heard?

Tags: game-industry

I was wondering how I could get a developer to hear about my idea. I don't really care if my idea gets "stolen", I only want it to be heard. So do you know how I could do this, or am I just being stupid? Again, I only want to know what the developer thinks of the idea, I'm not asking the developer to make it. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: See also [1% idea, 99% execution](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17663/1-idea-99-execution)

Comment: There's always the [halfbakery](http://www.halfbakery.com/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Get [enough rep](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat), ask about it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) here.
- Post your idea on [reddit](http://reddit.com/r/gamedev) (for brutally honest feedback).
- Post your idea on [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/17-game-design/) (make sure to read [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/260813-going-to-post-your-game-idea-read-this-first/) first).
- Pick some other popular game development site that's discussion oriented and post it there.